# How to display Arduino serial data to python gui?

Tags: python, user-interface, arduino, pyserial

I am working on project in which I am getting `data` from `Arduino serially` and accessing them into `Python`.To access data from arduino I am using `pyserial`. After that I have to display that data on `Python GUI`. 
How can I do this?

I am getting this data in `Arduino Serial Monitor`....

```
2.00
2.64
3.28
3.92
4.56
5.20
5.84
6.48
7.12
7.76
8.40
9.04
9.68
10.00
9.69
16.59
23.50
30.40
37.31
44.21
51.11
58.02
64.92
71.82
78.73
82.18
```

And using `pyserial` I am getting this data as `python output`...

```
[2.0]
[2.0, 2.64]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84, 6.48]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84, 6.48, 7.12]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84, 6.48, 7.12, 7.76]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84, 6.48, 7.12, 7.76, 8.4]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84, 6.48, 7.12, 7.76, 8.4, 9.04]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84, 6.48, 7.12, 7.76, 8.4, 9.04, 9.68]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84, 6.48, 7.12, 7.76, 8.4, 9.04, 9.68, 10.0]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84, 6.48, 7.12, 7.76, 8.4, 9.04, 9.68, 10.0, 9.69]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84, 6.48, 7.12, 7.76, 8.4, 9.04, 9.68, 10.0, 9.69, 16.59]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84, 6.48, 7.12, 7.76, 8.4, 9.04, 9.68, 10.0, 9.69, 16.59, 23.5]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84, 6.48, 7.12, 7.76, 8.4, 9.04, 9.68, 10.0, 9.69, 16.59, 23.5, 30.4]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84, 6.48, 7.12, 7.76, 8.4, 9.04, 9.68, 10.0, 9.69, 16.59, 23.5, 30.4, 37.31]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84, 6.48, 7.12, 7.76, 8.4, 9.04, 9.68, 10.0, 9.69, 16.59, 23.5, 30.4, 37.31, 44.21]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84, 6.48, 7.12, 7.76, 8.4, 9.04, 9.68, 10.0, 9.69, 16.59, 23.5, 30.4, 37.31, 44.21, 51.11]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84, 6.48, 7.12, 7.76, 8.4, 9.04, 9.68, 10.0, 9.69, 16.59, 23.5, 30.4, 37.31, 44.21, 51.11, 58.02]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84, 6.48, 7.12, 7.76, 8.4, 9.04, 9.68, 10.0, 9.69, 16.59, 23.5, 30.4, 37.31, 44.21, 51.11, 58.02, 64.92]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84, 6.48, 7.12, 7.76, 8.4, 9.04, 9.68, 10.0, 9.69, 16.59, 23.5, 30.4, 37.31, 44.21, 51.11, 58.02, 64.92, 71.82]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84, 6.48, 7.12, 7.76, 8.4, 9.04, 9.68, 10.0, 9.69, 16.59, 23.5, 30.4, 37.31, 44.21, 51.11, 58.02, 64.92, 71.82, 78.73]
[2.0, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.2, 5.84, 6.48, 7.12, 7.76, 8.4, 9.04, 9.68, 10.0, 9.69, 16.59, 23.5, 30.4, 37.31, 44.21, 51.11, 58.02, 64.92, 71.82, 78.73, 82.18]
```

In `python` I have used this code to get `Serial data`....

```
import serial
arduino = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, timeout = .1)
arduino_data = [] # declare a list
while True:
    data = arduino.readline()
    if data:
        arduino_data.append(float(data)) # Append a data to your declared list
        print arduino_data
```

Comment: What is the relevance of `pyserial` and `arduino` in your question, when it seems to be all about *how to display data in python gui*? Could you be a little more specific on *how you want to display your data*? Could you provide a *data example*? note: **edit** your question to add relevant information, don't use comments for that.

Comment: Great **edit**, upvoted. Now, *what is the end result that you want to achieve*? do you simply want to plot a live graph or you want an entire application around it?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin..Thanks for upvoting...Not live graph but can say entire application around it,i.e. just create a windows that can display serial data that I got in python shell.which I have displayed in myquestion as `pyserial output`.

Comment: Ok, then I think I am not able to help you on this. There are similar projects from which you could take inspiration, though. See [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/08/07/a-live-data-monitor-with-python-pyqt-and-pyserial), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754903/using-pyserial-to-plot-time-against-voltage-from-an-arduino-serial-port), [this](https://github.com/mba7/SerialPort-RealTime-Data-Plotter) and [this](https://github.com/Suyash458/SoftwareOscilloscope)

Comment: @PatrickTrentin..Ok thanks. I will try on that links.

Answer (score 1):

```
import serial
arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout = .1)
arduino_data = [] # declare a list
i=0;
while i<5:
    data = arduino.readline()
    if data:
        #arduino_data.append(data) # Append a data to your declared list
        print data
        i=i+1;


#try this code mate, i am beginner but did this for you i think i will work for you please
```